# Stuck on building a basic card game

Tags: python

I very new to programming and Python and trying to create a basic card game. Im stuck at getting the card from players hand to the middle. I successfully removed the card from players hand, but having hard time getting it to the middle of the board.

This is my idea of the removecard function, that should remove the card from player and add it to the middle.

```
def removecard(self):
        self.cards.pop()
        self.middlecards.append(self.cards.pop())
        self.howmanycards -=1
        self.middlecardscount +=1
```

```
class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fulldeck = []
        for a in suits:
            for b in ranks:
                self.fulldeck.append(Card(a,b))

    def __str__(self):
        showfull = ''
        for a in self.fulldeck:
            showfull +='\n' + Card.__str__(a)
        return showfull

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.fulldeck)

    def deal(self):
        newcard = self.fulldeck.pop()
        return newcard
```

```
class Hand:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        self.middlecards = []
        self.howmanycards = 0
        self.middlecardscount = 0



    def addcards(self,a):
        self.cards.append(a)
        self.howmanycards +=1


    def removecard(self):
        self.cards.pop()
        self.middlecards.append(self.cards.pop())
        self.howmanycards -=1
        self.middlecardscount +=1
```

Comment: Not sure if this helps but..... You’re calling self.cards.pop() twice. Try card = self.cards.pop() then self.middlecards.append(card). Also why are you keeping counters of the cards when Python has len(...) for the number of elements in a list.

Comment: good point about the counters, thanks.
i tried your suggestions and although it doesnt produce any errors it doesnt update the middlecard list either. Dont know why

Comment: Please detail in functional terms, what you mean by "having trouble".  You didn't give a full [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but your code is reasonably clear.  How does your chosen card *not* get to the middle?  You remove two cards frmo the hand, placing the second in the middle, but allowing the first to disappear entirely from the game.  As @mrblewog suggested, this is probably not what you intended.  Simply delete the first line (pop only); the second one is a good way to move the card (pop and append the return value).

Answer (score 0):

```
class Hand:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        self.middlecards = []

    def removecard(self):
        self.middlecards.append(self.cards.pop())


hand = Hand()
hand.cards = ['1','2','3']
hand.removecard()
print(hand.middlecards)
```

This is a sample example of what you are trying to do